# First steps for membership software

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, civimail, civimember

My european organization (~ 500 members) wants to buy a membership software. So far we have used a german site, but due to their advertisements within e-mails sent by us, we are not satisfied. In addition, e-mails are not registered by my club as its sender, but an extremely spam-suspicious address is generated (e.g. 1239123jasdka83@[member sofware].de) and our mail is sent to the respective member. This is not a sign of security or quality. Therefore we would like to use new software.

The following points are extremely important to us:

- Automated/semi-automated member maintenance: We do not want to enter member data manually on the software. Therefore it is possible to link an online membership application (already existing) with the software or can it connect to our website for the membership application?
- Automated direct debit procedure: It must be possible for contributions to be collected from members on a specific date or other day, depending on their profile. If it is possible, how long should it take to set up automation?
- The automated direct debit system must be compatible with our membership fee schedule: there is a deadline, assumed to be 01.01, where fees are debited from all members. This day is therefore fixed. If a member joins, 2 months or less before the next deadline, he only has to pay the fee on the deadline.
  If a member joins, but more than two months before the next key date, a full membership fee will be deducted on his entry date. In addition, a regular membership fee will be deducted on the 01.01. key date. Can this unique constellation be mapped in your software?

To the another important point:

- Emails must be able to be sent from OUR mail address to members. The mails must of course arrive without advertising.

If the above three points are feasible, we are interested in any appropriate software and would like to get an estimate of the monthly/annual costs and how to proceed.

Thank you for your helpful answers.

Comment: Dear Samba21, I am sure you will get some answers here but you will not get an estimate here. CiviCRM is open-source and community-maintained software so there is not an "owner" type of organization reading these questions and providing answers. I would recommend you check on https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors if there is a local expert you can contact for an estimate (and there will be German ones).

Comment: Hi @Samba12, just on another note, you could ask your question in the CiviCRM mattermost and you may find some good answers to your questions from the community - https://chat.civicrm.org/